# will printf() conflict with the 232 serial communcation in embedded linux system?

Tags: linux, printf, embedded-linux

I'm having an embedded linux device. I'm using ttyO2 as my console.
However, at the same time my MCU need to perform RS232 communicate with a device through ttyO2.

Now lets say if the MCU and the device are communicating, and I type some characters in the console terminal, or there runs another thread that will invoke function `printf()` , will that conflicts with the 232 communication? is the `printf()` outputting to the ttyO2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I'm using ttyO2 as my console.
```

so you configured serial port as console, printf() output will be redirected to console. i.e serial port.

Answer (score 1):

If your board is communicating over RS232 with an external device, then then board and the device are connected with a serial cable. How can you also connect the the serial terminal?

In any case, using the same serial port as console and as a communication port is a **bad** idea, because there are a lot of things that can be printed: the console I/O, the kernel debug, other programs output to stdout and so on.... Do you think you can have a stable communication with all that *"junk"* on the wire?

Comment: can you explain more about the console I/O? Is the terminal I/O a type of console I/O?

Comment: with console I/O, I consider all the normal things that are written on a console, that is for example the login prompt and the username that you type to log into the system.